# Better way to process parameters python

Tags: python, argv

Im using this algorithm to filter the parameters that the user passes trought argv in Python and i want to know if theres a better or more correct way to do-it for a generic application.

```
from sys import argv

# Generate parameters list
paramList = []
for item in argv[1:]:
    if item.startswith("--"):
        paramList.append(item[2:])
    elif item.startswith("-"):
        for subitem in item[1:]:
           paramList.append(subitem)
```

Comment: [Yeah, kind of](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: [There are other options as well](http://docopt.org/).

Comment: depending on what you want to do, argparse might be useful. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html